# checking a proper date format causing trouble?

Tags: c#

I have a code that checks a string whether in date format or not.
If it is a date format I will write it in proper date formate, otherways take it as  incoming string.

My normal date string format is

```
2016-08-08T18:30:00.000Z //if string is in this format only it should go inside if case.


namespace ConsoleApplication3
   {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var answerString = "11,10";
                DateTime dDate;

                if (DateTime.TryParse(answerString, out dDate))
                {
                    var date = DateTime.Parse(answerString);
                    // var indianTime = CovertToDefaultTimeZone(date);
                    answerString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Console.WriteLine(answerString);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(answerString);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use TryPars()e instead of Parse().

Comment: What's your actual problem ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [DateTimeParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in the format string corresponding to your required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` like this

```
DateTime result; 
var formatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffZ";
var isValidDate = DateTime.TryParseExact("2016-08-08T18:30:00.000Z", formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
```

Comment: it worked, can i use tryparse instead of tryparse exact?

Comment: @Vispriya - TryParseExact checks if the string is exactly matching the format strint. TryParse deals with multiple string variants that represent a DateTime. As you stated in your post you want to check a specific format; therefore is TryParseExact suitable for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(answerString,"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out dDate))
    {
                    //var date = DateTime.Parse(answerString); no need to parse again parsed date is in dDate
                    // var indianTime = CovertToDefaultTimeZone(date);
                    answerString = dDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Console.WriteLine(answerString);
                    Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Use `TryParseExact` method.

Comment: change date fomat in try parse exact method

Comment: before if case?

Comment: inside TRyparseexact method. Check the modified code.

Comment: why tryparse exact? what is the diffrence btween tryparse and trypareexact.

Comment: TryParseExact helps you to specify exact date format for date string. TryParse Doesn't have this facility. This helps you to make your code independent of execution environment as TryParse expects a different date string in different execution enviroments